# How to filter Redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Is it okay to add more info to an action so component specific reducers (and sagas/whatever side effect lib you're using) can filter them?

Example:

```
function reducerComponentA(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_FETCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
      break;

    case START_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
      };
      break;
  }

  return state;
}
```

and

```
function reducerComponentB(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_FETCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
      break;

    case START_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
      };
      break;
  }

  return state;
}
```

Notice how both reducers observes the same action and act on them (show a loading animation). Now if the screen/component that these reducers are related to are both in memory, the `START_FETCH` will cause to both of them to show the loading animation, maybe even overlapping (because it's global). Is filtering actions by screen/component a good solution?

Like this:

```
function reducerComponentA(state, action) {
  if (action.currentScreen === 'ScreenA') {
    switch (action.type) {
      ...
    }
  }

  return state;
}
```

This seems to more of a problem on React Native, because if you're using a Navigator, there's a chance multiple screens will be loaded at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'mount' reducer to the different slices of the state. To achieve this, you can add `path` to the action, and in the reducer, update corresponding slice of the state.

It can be similar to:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === '...') {
    return _.set(_.deepClone(state), `${action.path}.isLoading`, false)
  } else return state;
}
```

In other words, action determines which part of the state reducer will be operating with.

Note that this example above is extremely inefficient and only for demo purpose. Instead of cloning the state, some immutability helpers should be used: [kolodny/immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper), [mweststrate/immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer), other.

### UPD

Imagine you have action and reducer for an input state:

```
const UPDATE_VALUE = 'UPDATE_VALUE';
const updateValue = (value) => ({ type: UPDATE_VALUE, value })

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === UPDATE_VALUE) {
    return { ...state, input: action.value }
  } else return state;
}
```

And you want to use this action/reducer for many different inputs. The action can be supplied with
a property path that indicates which part or the state should be updated, and eventually which input
will receive new props:

```
const UPDATE_VALUE = 'UPDATE_VALUE';
const updateValue = (value, path) => ({ type: UPDATE_VALUE, value, path })

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === UPDATE_VALUE) {
    return { ...state, [action.path]: action.value }
  } else return state;
}
```

This can be used then:

```
dispatch(updateValue(event.target.value, 'firstNameInput'))
dispatch(updateValue('Doe', 'lastNameInput'))
```

The code at the beginning of the answer is a generic version of the latter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution, could you elaborate more?

Comment: sure, I'll write an example

Comment: I don't think this is really the problem I'm having, and it doesn't seem to be a good practice (after all, you're leaving for the component/container to know how to update a state, instead of the reducer).